# Number of observations required to approximate discrete random variable

Tags: random-variable, markov-process

I am trying to understand if, given a discrete random variable, there exists a formalised approach for determining the number of observations required to "well approximate" said variables true distribution. Obviously this requires a more rigorous definition of what is meant by "well approximate", and I am open to guidance on this matter.

My current approach relies on simulation to determine the number of observations required for the distance between the true distribution and its approximation to fall below an acceptable threshold (with distance measured using a KL-divergence based metric). However, I am hoping there may be an analytical solution and/or a less subjective decision criteria that can be used.

For context, this problem relates to the modelling of data using a Markov chain, and is concerned with the amount of data required to be able to model a state in a Markov chain.